# How can I get an array of Strings i.e.. [String] to show up in the custom collection view cell using storyboard

Tags: swift, text, uicollectionview, label, cell

In the Storyboard:

The datasource and delegate are connected from the LFCollectionView to the LFCollectionViewController.  The reuseIdentifier is set to LFCell in the CollectionViewCell. The label inside the CollectionViewCell is named cellLabel and has an outlet to my custom LFCollectionViewCell. I want the outlet cellLabel to display the elements in my array of strings lFContainerLabel within each cell container in the collection.  I am missing something, or going about this all wrong.  I do not have a nib.  I don't know how to use those.  Is a nib a must in this scenario?

```
import UIKit

var lFContainerLabel: [String] = []
private let reuseIdentifier = "LFCell"

class LFCollectionView: UICollectionView { }
class LFNavigationController: UINavigationController { }
class LFCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!

}

class LFCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.register(LFCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in LFCollectionViewController: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ LFCollectionViewController: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return lFContainerLabel.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ LFCollectionViewController: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let lFCell = LFCollectionViewController.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell!

        var myIndex: Int = 0

        lFCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        lFCell?.accessibilityElements = lFContainerLabel

        myIndex = indexPath.item

        lFCell?.cellLabel?.text = lFContainerLabel[myIndex]
        return lFCell!
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you giving `lFContainerLabel` values at any point? And if so, where?

Comment: Yes.  I get colored boxes, containers,  not exactly sure I know the correct terms here.  The number of boxes correspond to the number of elements in my array lFContainerLabel which is being filled in another module.  After I get this working I was going to add Drag and Drop protocols, is my Flow Delegate maybe causing this?  I feel like I am missing some basic concepts here.

Comment: @CodeNinja basically I asked my technical support for development and the answer is under nondisclosure which was just a link to a lot of documentation that is available to me.  However, I feel like converting a string to an image must be done every day in iOS and somebody out there has the short answer, without reading the non disclosed data.  If anybody can help me change a string into an image let me know.